# Como alterar icon em Java relacionando com o estado presente no Banco de Dados MySQL

Tags: java, netbeans, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um Sistema hoteleiro e só falta a parte onde mostra o estado do quarto (Disponível, Ocupado, Limpeza), mas não sei como implementar os icon de acordo com o banco de dados, queria que aparecesse os icon de acordo com a quantidade de quartos cadastrados. Alguém por favor para me ajudar.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bom vamos la, a tabela deve conter pelo menos uma coluna chamada vamos supor "StatusA" e "StatusB"  podendo receber os valores 0 para disponível, 1 para Ocupado e 2 para Limpeza, já StatusB você pode anotar se 0-disponivel e 1-possui hospede, assim ao listar os dados da tabela seu codigo ira pegar o resultado do status atual, vamos supor 2 que seria limpeza e retornar para a pessoa o icone de uma vassoura por exemplo, após o término da faxina a camareira vai e marca outro quarto, a rotina  verifica que a camareira iniciou outro quarto, e como ela não pode estar em dois quartos ao mesmo tempo atualiza o quarto que ela marcou anteriormente para 1 disponível se não estiver com statusb=0, lembra de avisar a "faxineira" que ela deve desmarcar o último quarto quando não anotar mais nenhum, porque senão o último quarto vai ficar marcado como em faxina até alguém liberar o quarto(efetuar checkout) ou outra faxineira entrar nele e partir para outro...